# Prevent Excel from rounding microseconds in timestamp

Tags: excel

I am importing a text file to excel with timestamps that have microsecond precision in the format HH:MM:SS:000000

ex: 17:37:34.027391

I have tried custom formatting but it will only give you milliseconds and round off the rest. After looking around I haven't found any good way to keep the microsecond precision.

Comment: Best way to work around this is to not show date in HH:MM:SS format. Instead show it as a number if what you care about is preserving precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:
When you import a file using the Text Import Wizard, you need to choose 'Text' as the Column data format on step 3 to prevent Excel from being able to round the microseconds. I didn't notice this window when first importing and didn't see this answered anywhere else. Not sure why I got down-voted.

Comment: Yea thanks, your solution works. I was creating a tab separated file using python and we are examining time in microseconds. All the other solutions were garbage. StackOverflow should keep yours and delete the other solutions.